# MySQL Where column contained in string

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot figure out how to query a table on a column being contained in a string.

Table companies:

```
id | title
----------
 1 | abc
 2 | abcd
 3 | bcde
 4 | xyfa
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE CONTAINS("ABCDEFG Ltd", title)

SELECT * FROM companies WHERE CONCAT("%", title, "%") LIKE "ABCDEFG Ltd"
```

I would like to return:

```
id | title
----------
 1 | abc
 2 | abcd
 3 | bcde
```

Comment: The `CONTAINS()` version is going to throw an error (unless you have created a user-defined function named of that name, since that's not a builtin function of MySQL). The query with the `LIKE` comparison will execute, but it's not going to return any rows. It doesn't matter what value is found in the `title` column, the comparison never going to find a literal percent character `'%'` at the as the first character in the literal string `'ABC...'`.  (The percent character is only a *wild card* when it appears in the string on the *right side* of the LIKE comparison.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies
WHERE 'ABCDEFG Ltd' LIKE CONCAT('%', title, '%');
```

That is, the pattern is whatever is in `title` with wildcards on either side.  You want to know if your company name matches it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Gordon's answer would be [INSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) function

`WHERE INSTR(title, 'ABCDEFG Ltd') <> 0`

Normally, I recommend against function calls in `WHERE` conditions if possible, but putting a field on the right hand side of a `LIKE` and/or `CONCAT`ing it is just as bad; but in this case one or the other is unavoidable. I can't say for sure which version will be faster, you should try both. I would **guess** mine might be, since the like-concat likely involves a string copy then a compare; whereas the INSTR **should** only need a compare; but with MySQL it is not always obvious.